# Calling JSON data through the function inside the php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

Actually , I did the JSON calling from the PHP file named as student_detail.php

> localhost/demo/student_details.php

I need to call the JSON file inside the student_details.php file. like

> localhost/demo/student_details/get_Students_Details

by calling this way it shows an error like object not found. Here my code

```
<?php

include('database.php');

class student_details
{
    public function get_Students_Data()
    {
        $query = "select * from student_table";

        $result = mysql_query($query);

        $student_data = array();

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $student_data[] = array(
                'Student Id'    =>  $row["student_id"],
                'Register No'   =>  $row["student_register_no"],
                'Roll No'       =>  $row["student_roll_no"],
                'Name'          =>  $row["student_name"],
                'Date Of Birth' =>  $row["student_DOB"],
                'Gender'        =>  $row["student_gender"],
                'Nationality'   =>  $row["student_nationality"],
                'City'          =>  $row["student_city"],
                'Pincode'       =>  $row["student_pincode"]
            );
        };

        echo json_encode($student_data,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
}

?>
```

How do I resolve it.?

Comment: Are you using a PHP framework like CodeIgniter? Are you using a .htaccess to convert your URL into PHP "GET" arguments that can then be used in your function? With the limited information provided answers will be few... Additionally, make sure you are meticulous with your function names and their spelling when you call them.

Comment: Setup your server properly. If you want to call it like that you likely need a controller or a rewrite rule for your webserver.  In addition consider checking out the `mysqli` functions for a object oriented approach.

Answer (score 0):

You are using "clean urls", which pure PHP doesnt support.
Its unclear if you are using a framework which does support that or not.

Your code, as is, should work if you are using a framework with clean urls.

Please provide some more informations for further help.

---

If you do NOT use a framework, all you have to do is create a new file, which will be called if you want to request a JSON response. Then you create a new object of your student_details class and call the method get_Student_Data().

i.e:

```
<?php

include('classes/student_details.php');

$student = new student_details;
$student->get_Student_Data();
```

---

**Unrelated, but still important:** do NOT use mysql_* functions, since they are deprecated in PHP 5.5 and removed from PHP 7. Use mysqli_* or PDO instead.